# Angular Component library dependent library module not working

Tags: angular, npm, pdftron

I created on component library where I used PDFTron to show PDF file with Annotation feature. Now when I going to integrate my library in another project its not loading PDFTron library modules and getting below error:

Error:

```
core.mjs:6484 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _pdftron_webviewer__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not a function
TypeError: _pdftron_webviewer__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not a function
    at MyFirstNpmProjComponent.ngAfterViewInit (my-first-npm-proj.mjs:36:9)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2533:22)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2502:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2453:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9555:21)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10655:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9280:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9534:13)
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (core.mjs:9598:9)
    at tickRootContext (core.mjs:10829:9)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1255:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1209:1)
    at zone.js:1321:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:434:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25463:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:433:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:205:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:620:1)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:520:1)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1656:1)
```

Not sure why its not able to read PDFTron webviewer module.

I stuck on this issue for the last 2 days and I tried most of the ways to get it loaded on my project but failed with all the solutions.

Any help is appreciated!

My Library Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/my-first-npm-proj

Where I use the below code for loading PDF with annotation:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
      WebViewer({
        path: 'assets/lib',
        initialDoc: this.initialDoc
      }, this.viewer.nativeElement).then(instance => {
        this.wvInstance = instance;
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log("PDF error:",error);
      })
  }
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to review our angular sample https://github.com/PDFTron/webviewer-angular-sample? Were you able to run this sample?

Comment: Yes, this sample is working very well even it's working on my existing project with direct integration but while I put it under my angular component there it's not able to find the JS function.

Comment: The issue seems to be related to your webpack setup. Can you provide us with steps to reproduce this issue?